# How many imports can a single Java program have?

Tags: java

For example: Can I have both `import java.util.Scanner;` and `import java.util.Random;` in the same instance?

Comment: Have you tried anything related to that? Or are you asking if there is an exact number of imports a class can contain?

Comment: It'd take about 2 minutes to try. About as long after asking this question, as my comment not answering it.

Answer (score 4):

There's no explicit limit to the number of classes you can import within a single file, nor to the number of user-defined classes you can have throughout your own projects.

There are *practical* limits - you're rarely going to have more than twenty or thirty imports in a single file, at max, just because you're not going to be *using* most of them. But if you need to use `java.util.Scanner` and `java.util.Random` in the same class, feel free to import both. Java certainly won't stop you.

Similarly, there are practical limits on the number of user-defined classes you will have in your own projects. Your own computer only has so much disk space to store files, and the project you're working on won't be infinitely complex so as to require an infinite number of files. If it were, Java wouldn't stop you - you'd run into hardware limitations first.

It's even possible to use two different classes with the same name, such as `java.awt.List` and `java.util.List` (which serve two different purposes), though Java won't let you `import` them both at the same time and you'd need to refer to at least one of them in code by their full path instead of just by `List`, for disambiguation:

```
//import java.awt.List;
//import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

...

java.awt.List myListComponent = new java.awt.List();
java.util.List<Integer> myArrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Comment: Nope, this wont compile

Comment: @GyroGearless I got it wrong, thanks for the heads-up. Double-checked, and it turns out `import` can't be used in this case, though both classes can still be used with their full names. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: You can use import for one of them, the other has to be referenced by the full name.